# Remainder using Modular Arithmetic

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

The question is to find out $2005^{2007^{2009}}\bmod 7$ or the remainder when $2005^{2007^{2009}}$ is divided by $7$.
My steps $: \\
2005\equiv3\pmod 7\\
2005^3\equiv3^3\equiv-1\pmod7\\
2005^{2007}\equiv-1^{669}\equiv-1\pmod7$

How do I proceed? Please help!!!

Comment: You can't work with nested exponents in that order. See my answer where I explain how to do this step-by-step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $2005$ is not divisible by $7$ – more precisely, $2005\equiv 3\bmod 7$, you can use *lil' Fermat*:
$$2005^{2007^{2009}}\equiv 3^{2007^{2009}}\equiv 3^{2007^{2009}\bmod 6}\mod 7.$$
Now $\;2007\equiv 3\mod 6$, and it happens that, for all $n$, $3^n\equiv 3\mod 6$, so that
$$2005^{2007^{2009}}\equiv 3^3\mod 7.$$

Comment: I did not get the jump from $3^{2007^{2009}}$ to $3^{2007^{2009}mod6}$

Comment: pls tell me how you did that. Fermat's little theorem says something else

Comment: It says that for any number $a$ not divisible by $7$, $\;a^6\equiv 1\mod 7$. Isn't it equivalent to saying that $\;a^n\equiv a^{n\bmod 6}\mod 7\,$?

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Your beginning was promising

$$2005=3\pmod 7\;,\;\;\text{and}\;\;3^3=-1\pmod 7\,,\,\,3^6=1\pmod 7$$

Now, $\;2007^{2009}=0\pmod 3\;$ and also odd , so ... (Try to complete the argument)

Answer (score 1):

Note that $A^{\large B^{\Large N}}\!$ means $A^{\large (B^{\Large N})}$ not $(A^{\large B})^{\large N}$ so we cannot proceed bottom-up as you did. Instead we need to work top-down:  we can use $\,3^{\large 6}\equiv 1\pmod{\!7}\,$ to do [modular exponent reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242), i.e.

$\!\bmod 7\!:\,\ 3^{\large 6}\!\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, 3^{\large N}\!\equiv 3^{\large N\bmod 6}\! \equiv 3^{\large\color{#c00}3}\!\equiv 6\   $ since, by CPR = [Congruence Power Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)

$$\begin{align} N\bmod 6\, &=\, 2007^{\large 2009}\!\bmod 6 \\[.2em]
&=\ \ \ \ \ \  3^{\large 2009}\bmod 6\ \ \ \ \  {\rm by}\ \ 2007\equiv 3\!\!\!\pmod{\!6}\ \ \&\ \ \rm CPR\\[.2em]
&=\ \  3(3^{\large 2008}\bmod 2)\ \ \ \ \text{by mod Distributive Law (below)}   \\[.2em]
&=\ \  3(1^{\large 2008} \bmod 2)\ \ \  {\,\rm by}\ \ 3\equiv 1\!\!\!\pmod{\!2}\ \ \&\ \ \rm CPR\\[.2em]
&= \ \ \color{#c00}3 \end{align}$$

where above we have applied $\ ab\bmod ac = a(b\bmod c) =$ [mod Distributive Law,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242) in order to simplify by factoring $\,3\,$ out of the $\!\bmod\!.\,$ This law is equivalent an  of CRT = Chinese Remainder Theorem, but its *operational* form makes it more convenient in many applications such as above.